# Using BT Business Hub 3 with separate DNS server

Tags: router, dhcp, wifi-configuration

We have a BT Business Hub 3 in our office to connect to the internet. We are a web development company and we have internal servers in our office that we want to be able to access from mobile phones for web site testing so we would like to allocate our own internal DNS servers when we get an IP address via DHCP.

On the BT Business Hub, we can specify an IP address range to be given out via DHCP, but cannot specify the DNS servers to use.

We have a working internal DHCP server on our internal network which we would like to connect to to obtain the IP address and DNS server settings. If we disable DHCP on the BT Business Hub then from my phone I can connect to the WIFI on the BT Business Hub but the phone then sits there saying 'Obtaining IP Address from ' and never actually gets an IP address.

So, does anyone know either:

1. Can I get the BT Business Hub to give out different DNS servers which it gives out an IP address via DHCP (I believe the answer to this is no)
2. Alternatively, why are the DHCP requests not getting through the BT Business Hub to our DHCP server? Is there some setting I haven't yet found?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: 9 months later and I wonder if you ever got this sorted? We have a similar issue and would like to use the hub's Time Schedule feature to restrict out-of-hours use and it's dependent on the hub's dhcp allocations. Thank you for your time and patience, I look forward to your reply!